# eclipse error in hibernate struts project

Tags: java, eclipse

when i tried to run a program it popped a window titled as " Problem Occured"  specifying that 
 Could not delete 
      D/wrkspace/ metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/MyProjectAdmin/WEB-INF/ classes/AdminLoginPackage. May be locked by another process

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and back on?

Comment: yes 
i already tried that .
:-(

Answer (score 0):

The WEB-INF/classes folder generally contains the compiled class files. You have something that is running and/or is viewing the files. Check for file browsers, running instances, etc, try rebooting the machine and deleting the files manually. That is what the lock is reporting.

Comment: i tried that brother
and i have no  file  open in any file  expkorer.. 
i would like to tell u one more thing that,,,,,

at the start i found cross on package name which told me package name cant start with capital letter. then i renamed it but nothing changed.  error is still there.

Comment: Have you tried in safe mode? There should be no reason if eclipse is not running & no instances of the application are running that this error should be occurring. If not, you'll have to create a new project and import those files. Possibly consider a virus scan, this really doesn't sound like an Eclipse issue.

Comment: yeah brother i am trying hard.
thanks for suggestion 
i m now working on it n will notify u .